# What happens if a node is down and we issue a delete and post the node is up?

Tags: cassandra, delete-row

What happens if we issue a delete on the cassandra cluster and the node is down. Consider a two node cassandra cluster

Tried to issue a truncate and it failed as one node was down.

Comment: Hi Vamsi, welcome to StackOverflow. Could you include in your question the steps you've taken to setup a cassandra cluster, followed by the command you executed which failed to delete the cluster (along with the error message). This information will better help us debug your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes due to network nodes are not able to gossip each other then we can get this type of error. however operation will be completed. have you checked the status of all nodes before running truncate command.

Answer (score 0):

If you run truncate when one of the nodes is down the truncate will fail.

REFER

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlTruncate.html